# Prove rigorously that there are exactly nine solutions to the simultaneous equations $x =1000(y^3−y)$ and $y = 1000(x^3−x)$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Prove rigorously that there are exactly nine solutions to the simultaneous equations $x =1000(y^3−y)$ and $y = 1000(x^3−x)$. That is, prove that there are exactly nine ordered pairs $(x,y)$ such that the two equations are satisfied.

By substitution I obtain

$$x^9-3x^7+3x^5-1.000001x^3+0.000000999999x=0$$
Wolfram Alpha gives me in fact 9 approximated solutions to this equation, some of which are very close:
$0$; $±0.001$; $±0.9995$; $±1$; $±1.0005$.
I can use the mean value theorem to find that there must be a solution between $0.9997$ and $1.0003$ and so on (I do this for the positive $x$, then the negative solutions are determined by symmetry).
However this is very artificial, I can do this because I already know a good approximation to the solutions, so I know which intervals I should take.
Is there a better way to solve the problem?

Edit: I now see one can easy guess the intervals also without knowing the solutions, by considering x=power of ten, or 1±x=power of ten (since it's easy to calculate p(x±1) knowing a polynomial p(x)), to see what the ruling term is and its sign. Though maybe it's not that obvious that the solutions are all close to 0 and 1.

Comment: Now, for the general case with $k$, are all roots real ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace $1000$ by $k$

Your equation in $x$ is
$$k^4 x^9-3 k^4 x^7+3 k^4 x^5+k^2 x-k^2\left(k^2+1\right) x^3-x=0$$
$x$ is an obvious factor and you are left with a quartic equation in $x^2$ which in turn factors as
$$x \left(k x^2-k-1\right) \left(k x^2-k+1\right) \left(k^2 x^4-k^2 x^2+1\right)=0$$ So, in your case,
$$x \left(1000 x^2-1001\right) \left(1000 x^2-999\right) \left(1000000 x^4-1000000
   x^2+1\right)=0$$